# Unlock the record to a group of users when it is submitted to approval process

Tags: apex

Is there any option to unlock the record to a group of users when it is submitted for approval.
I have a business scenario where a group of users has to modify the record even if it is submitted for approval.
I tried with apex using unlock method but it unlocks the record for all the users.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to unlock the record then the only other option you have is to give these users `The “Modify All” object-level permission for the given object` using this permission user can edit lock record.

[Specify Who Can Edit Locked Records](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=approvals_create_recordeditability.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a scenario when `Approval Process` won't lock the record, and create a `Validation Rule` to only allow for the records in `Approval Process` to be edited by a specific `Users` or `Profiles`. You would need 'In Approval' flag and set and erase it every time records going into or out from approval.